# Decimal system history

Tags: real-analysis, math-history, decimal-expansion

Today, "numbers" usually refer to real numbers and are most commonly conceptualized as consisting of all possible infinite decimal expansions (or binary expansions, etc). When did this way of thinking of numbers originate? What people were behind it? On a closely related note, when did mathematicians realize that irrational and transcendental numbers could be represented using infinitely many digits?

Thanks!

Comment: Liouville comes to mind, Cauchy, probably many others before them too...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal#History

Comment: [Simon Stevin’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin) [*De Thiende*](http://www.dbnl.org/tekst/stev001thie01_01/stev001thie01_01_0001.php) doesn’t appear to have an irrational example, but it shows that he recognized that $\frac{0.4}{0.03}=13.333\ldots$, with *oneyndelicke drien* ‘infinitely many threes’, and that *In sulcken ghevalle machmen soo naer commen als de saecke dat voordert, ende het overschoot verloren laten* ‘In such case one may come so near as the thing requires, and let the remainder be lost’.